# Can there be two different physical units (or dimensions) for a same physical quantity?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, non-linear-optics, photonics

I was going through this book "Nonlinear optics" by Robert W. Boyd for my postgraduate subject in Nonlinear optics and I came across the different orders of nonlinear susceptibilities. From my knowledge I know electric susceptibility is described as the degree of polarization of a dielectric material in response to an applied electric field.
Now my question is if this physical quantity describes the same thing in any material then why the dimensions are different for different orders of susceptibilities? Like second order susceptibility $\chi^2$ has the unit $m/V$, third order susceptibility $\chi^3$ has the unit $m^2/V^2$ and so on. If dimensions are different then doesn't it become a different physical quantity?

Comment: But doesn't each of the $\chi^2$ and $\chi^3$ parts multiply $E^2$ and $E^3$ respectively? With $E$ having units of V/m?

Comment: It is definitely be a different physical quantity, area is separate from length of course, but I agree there is more to the quation. It will definitely be the case that the infinite expansion of $\mathbf{P}$ will need some characteristic scale to be meaningful. I.e. if we say $\chi^2$ is small, that depends only on the units at play. So to really declare it small it must be small with respect to something of the same units. Is there any obvious scale in $m/V$ which non-linear optics takes place at/in? That may help you "understand" the expansion parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The 1st order susceptibly is "dipole moment per electric field", the second order moment is "quadruple moment per squared electric field", so that's how you get power of "volts per meter".

Meanwhile dipole moment is "charge time meters", so

$$ [Q][L] = [\chi_?][V]/[L] $$

so

$$[\chi_?] = [Q][L^2]/[V] $$

but no, the LHS is a dipole moment density...so divide by volume:

$$ [Q]/[L]^2 = [\chi][V]/[L] $$

so
$$[\chi] = [Q]/([V][L]) $$

but a coulomb per volt is a Farad. What? Oh wait:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit says permitivity in SI is measured in Farads per meter, so that's good.

Now use the fact that a quadruple moment has units $[C][L]^2$, and:

$$ Q_{ij}/[L]^3 = \epsilon^{(2)}_{ijkl}E_kE_l $$

to make those units work too.

Answer (score 3):

> Can there be two different physical units (or dimensions) for a same physical quantity?

Different units - yes. We can measure speed in kilometres per hour or metres per second or miles per hour or light years per fortnight etc. etc.

Different dimensions - no. All of the different units for speed have the same dimensions $LT^{-1}$. If a quantity appears to have different dimensions in different contexts then what is actually happening is the same name or label is being applied to two different physical quantities - which is confusing, but can occur. For example, [conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity) can mean electrical conductivity, thermal conductivity or hydraulic conductivity, but each of these has different dimensions, so they are three distinct physical attributes.

Comment: I heard that mass has  inverse length dimension, in some units, which seems to contradict your statements

Answer (score 2):

No. Different physical quantities generally do not have the same physical *dimensions*. They can *rarely* have the same units but are referred to as different quantities *c.f*., torque and work done both have units of $Nm$ or $\text{force}\times\text{distance}$ but they are different in a subtle way, related to the fact that one is dot product between force and distance while the other is a cross product between distance and force.

To address your example, as mentioned in my comment above, each of the terms in the expression involving $\chi^2,\chi^3,\chi^4\ldots\chi^i$ multiply electric field terms of power $(i-1)$ i.e., $E,E^2,E^3\ldots E^{i-1}$

This is relevant because the units for electric field $E$ are $Vm^{-1}$.  So the units for polarization (density) $$P\ \sim\ \epsilon_0\chi^iE^{i-1}$$ are retained for all orders of susceptibility $\chi$.

Comment: Yes I agree with you completely. $\chi^2$, $\chi^3$ ..... $\chi^i$ terms are multiplied with higher powers of Electric field so that each term in the series gives the unit of Polarization. My doubt is, the single entity $\chi^n$ is still called susceptibility and not something else. Considering the example that you have given, Torque and force have the same units but are referred to as different quantities.

Comment: I am sorry @soulfourier but Torque and force, by definition are not the same units, specially when torque's units are actually force$*$distance. So definitely not the same. Did you mean the units of work and of torque? Both are force$*$distance, however Torque is a vector, while work is a scalar (energy).

Answer (score 1):

For a general non-linear polarization density to work :
$$ P=P_{0} + \varepsilon_{0} \sum_n  \chi ^{(n)}E^{n}$$

one must have dimensions of electric susceptibility to be :
$$ \left[ \frac mV \right]^{n-1} $$, because we have a non-linear electric field strength here with units $[V/m]^n$, which also varies it's dimensions (different quantities actually), due to power $n$. Otherwise we will not get same definition of polarization density $\mathbf P$.